# back button shows previous page after logout in Symfony 2.1

Tags: session, symfony-2.1, cache-control

I have done project in `Symfony 2.1` in which session management works properly. i.e. after logout it shows login page.But while cliking on back button of browser it shows previous page which should not be shown as per requirements. If any action done on that page redirects to login screen again means no action is permitted after logout.
I tried different solution shown by others like:

In twig:

```
<META Http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<META Http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache">
<META Http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0">
```

But didn't workout for me.Any other way specially in `Symfony` to prevent this.Any suggestions are helpful.

Comment: Did you tried to save the pages? E.g., did you protected the pages with role control inside the Twig template?

Comment: I'm using Sonata admin bundle and fos user bundle for admin control stuff.Anything I have to add in twig?

Comment: When you create a page you can protect everything you want to render with something like `{%if app.user %}content{%else%}not allowed{%endif%}`. Moreover, you can check if the user has a specific role `{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %} content {% endif %}`

Comment: Is it necessary that it should be beginning of the page?. My standard layout contain many blocks which is extended. and some extended block contain {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %} content {% endif %}

Comment: Mine is not a best practice or an asnwer, it is just a suggestion! Try if using the `{%if app.user %}content{%else%}not allowed{%endif%}` the page is shown or not when you press the back button after the logout.

Comment: I tried. It doesn't look like it is accessing that page.Is is loading from browser cache?

Comment: Maybe it is! Bu if the user logged out nothing should happen! A possibile solution is to set the expiration date to the pages, e.g. [read here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/http_cache.html#expiration-with-the-expires-header) and the subsequent sections.

Comment: Logout working properly.Even if page is displayed no action is allowed on that page.It will redirect to login page.But I don't want to display page itself.I'll try to set expire date and check

Comment: It doesn't look like solution.Might be it depending on browser